# Limit questions on the front page / above the fold per-tag

Tags: feature-request

Right now, the front page looks like a LoL site, not a gaming site. I get that this is because the tournament is going on, and that's going to drive a lot of traffic and be good and so on - but I have no interest in it, and most friends I send to this site have no interest in it. If it looks like a LoL site, or a LoL dominated site, they're going to leave. I had similar problems during the Mass Effect push, but nowhere near this bad - I needed to page-down thrice to see a single non-LoL question (which was an old useless Skyrim bump). (Yes, I've personally hidden my ignored tags, but that doesn't help users who stumble across the site.)

Would it be possible to limit the number of front page questions per-tag? Say, the first X (5-10) questions would be purely time-based, but then the next X wouldn't contain anything with a tag already shown more than Y (2-3) times in those top 2X?

Or it doesn't even really need to be a limit; questions could all get their normal time on the page, but we'd push questions with extremely common tags down faster.

Comment: nice idea, although I'd already be happy if the amount of questions per page would be determined _after_ hiding questions of ignored tags - at the moment I see 27 questions on the front page instead of 50 due to ignoring LoL...

Comment: @Zommuter you're not the only one who will be happy if that is addressed... there are like 6 *open* feature-requests on meta.so about that on a regular basis :)

Comment: I've just blacklisted the LoL tag :) Though limiting tags on the front page seems like an okay idea, it does cause some problems; front page is supposed to have the most recent content, this could potentially hide bad edits/new posts that aren't seen because of the limit.

Comment: [related](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/is-the-community-sponsorship-program-working-a-little-too-well), [related](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/923/are-there-too-many-starcraft-2-single-game-questions), [related](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4161/overwhelmed-about-mass-effect-3-promo-missions)

Comment: @Resorath: Related but I think this is the first time we've gotten new users posting a question per hour _each_ for an "old" game, and it's questionable how many of them are going to stay users when LoL awards are no longer involved. I expect some of this for new releases - 16/50 for The Witcher 2 on release seems reasonable to me, and most new users would expect that. 23/50 for a game that everyone who isn't playing it has already heard of and written it off because they're not interested - that's going to scare them off entirely.

Comment: I also think my request is a bit different because it's focused on _diverse visibility_. I don't want to restrict questions people can ask; I don't think it's bad we're getting these. I think it's bad that right now the site looks like a LoL site, and I think we can fix that without having to really disadvantage anyone interested in LoL. The value of Stack Exchange is in being able to answer the long tail, _not_ in being able to provide answers for the Internet's game du jour, and the site doesn't give that impression right now.

Comment: Having lots of questions is a GOOD thing.  We're still not at the new question rate of Stack Overflow itself.  As we continue to grow people will need to adjust to the fact that they don't have to review every new question on the site.  Use your favorite tags and RSS feeds to find new question.

Comment: @bwarner: Showing only lots of questions about _one game_ is not a good thing. Even in the height of Facebook mania on SO, visiting the front page tells you _this is a site about programming_, not _this is a site about Facebook_.

Comment: @Joe The "problem" is so temporary that it doesn't seem worth worrying about.  I don't think we should be arbitrarily pushing questions off the front page just because we have too many users interested in a particular game, regardless of how new it is.

Comment: @bwarner: It's not temporary if it happens 1-2 weeks of every month for some game people already can't get away from. If I just wanted a site to answer questions about MW3, Skyrim, Mass Effect, and LoL, I don't need a Stack Exchange site for that. (And let's be honest - most of these questions are terrible, and from users that are only here for the bribes.)

Comment: Not to mention, it's drowning out questions about games that are actually new, might attract new users naturally, and have genuine unknown basic questions - the exact thing the original promotional efforts were intended to attract.

Comment: [Also related, and unfortunately by-design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21093/questions-per-page-not-honored-when-using-ignored-tags)